# Removing edges of tree in a forest and adding others edges to the same set of vertices of the tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I am tryng show the following result:

Let $F$ a forest and $T_1$ a tree with $T_1 \subseteq F$(subgraph of $F$). If $T_1'$ is a tree with $V(T_1') = V(T_1)$, then $F-E(T_1) \cup E(T_1')$ is a forest.

Follows the my argument:

Since $T_1$ is a tree, then for each vertices pair $u,v$ in $T_1$, we have that exists a unique path of $u$ to $v$ in $T_1$. Since $F$ is a forest, then for each $u,v$ in $T_1$ we have that $u$ and $v$ belongs to the differents connected component in $F-E(T_1)$.
Similarly, by definition, we have for each $u, v$ in $V(T_1')$, exists a unique path from $u$ to $v$ in $T_1'$. Moreover, $T_1'$ is acyclic.
Therefore, $(F-E(T_1)) \cup E(T_1')$ is a forest.

The argument is correct?

Comment: The following point is not very clear in your reasoning. Why between $u$ and $v$ there is only one path in the graph $F-E(T)+E(T')$?

Comment: In $F$, exists only one path from $u$ to $v$,(path belongs at $T_1$) because $F$ is acyclic. Then between u and v there is only one path in $F-E(T_1) + E(T_1') .

Comment: What if $u$ or $v$ or both do not lie in $V(T)$?

Comment: I think that in this case(when $u \notin V(T)$ or $v \notin V(T)$) the paths from $u$ to $v$ are the same in $F$ and in $F-E(T) \cup E(T')$, ok?

Comment: Note that $V(T) = V(T')$

Comment: I offer my reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that I am wrong, but it seems to me that it is not so simple here.

1. We can assume that $F$ is a tree (discarding all those connected components which have no common vertices with $T$).
2. We will now prove that the graph $H=F-E(T)+E(T')$ is a tree.
3. Let us prove the connectivity of $H$. Let $u,v\in V(H)$. Then in the graph $F$ there is a path $P$ between these vertices. Let us move along this path from $u$ to $v$. Let $u_1$ be the first vertex and $v_1$ the last vertex on this path lying in $V(T')$. Since $u_1,v_1\in V(T')$ and $T'$ is a tree, then $u_1$ and $v_1$ can be connected by $u_1\ldots v_1$ of $T'$. Then $u\ldots u_1\ldots v_1\ldots v$ is a path in graph $H$.
4. Prove that graph $H$ has no cycles. Reasoning from the contrary. Let $C$ be a cycle in graph $H$. It is clear that a cycle $C$ must have a vertex not lying in $V(T)=V(T')$ (otherwise we get a cycle in $T'$). On the other hand, at least one vertex of $C$ must lie in $V(T')$ (otherwise we get a cycle in $F-V(T)$).
   Let $u$ be a vertex of the cycle $C$ and $u\notin V(T')$. There are at least two vertices $x,y\in V(C)\cap V(T')$ (why?). We can assume that there are no other vertices from $V(T')$ on the arc $x\ldots u\ldots y$ of cycle $C$. But then in $T$ there exists a path between $x$ and $y$, which together with the arc $x\ldots u\ldots y$ gives us a cycle in the graph $F$. Contradiction.

Comment: I not understanded well why we can assume that $F$ is a tree.

Comment: In the result that described above $F$ is a forest.

Comment: "I not understand well why we can assume that $F$ is a tree"
I'll try to explain.

Let $F=F_1+\ldots+F_s$, where $F_i$ is a tree for each $i$. Since $T$ is a tree and $F_i$ are connected components of $F$, there exists $i$ for which $T\leq F_i$.
If we prove that $F_i-E(T)+E(T')$ is a tree, then it follows that $F-E(T)+E(T')$ is a forest.